# Linkifying backticked code containing [] adds backslashes

Tags: bug, editor

When turning a string containing square brackets such as `sys.argv[1]` into a link by selecting it and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> I get the following result:

```
[`sys.argv\[1\]`][1]
```

This is rendered as [`sys.argv\[1\]`](http://stackoverflow.com) which is obviously incorrect. Instead, the markdown should look like this:

```
[`sys.argv[1]`][1]
```

which in turn results in a proper link with the proper text: [`sys.argv[1]`](http://stackoverflow.com)